# Extract particular value from NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

How do I extract values from `NDSolveValue` at particular point: for example how do I extract the last point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the result of `NDSolveValue` is an interpolation function. Example.

```
sol[x_] = 
 NDSolveValue[{  y''[x] + y[x] == 0 , y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, "StopIntegration"]}, y[x], {x, 0, 20}]
```

you can do `sol["Methods"]` to see a bunch of descriptve data available:

> {"Coordinates", "DerivativeOrder", "Domain", "ElementMesh",
>   "Evaluate", "Grid", "InterpolationMethod", "InterpolationOrder", 
>   "MethodInformation", "Methods", "OutputDimensions", "Periodicity", 
>   "PlottableQ", "Properties", "QuantityUnits", "ValuesOnGrid"}

`Grid` holds the actual evaluation points, so the last point is:

```
 end=sol["Grid"][[-1,1]]
```

> 3.14159

in this case since we didn't know the domain in advance its useful to set the range for `Plot`:

```
 Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, end}]
```

[image]

here is a plot of the actual solution points:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{Flatten[sol["Grid"]], sol["ValuesOnGrid"]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the last point, there's an even easier method. Using george's example:

```
NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}, y[20], {x, 20}]
   0.912945
```

and you can see that the value at `x == 20` is returned at once.

If you're using `WhenEvent[]` for event detection, you can use the second argument to throw a result at once:

```
Quiet[Catch[NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1, 
                    WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, Throw[{x, y[x]}]; "StopIntegration"]},
                   {}, {x, ∞}]], NDSolveValue::noout]
   {3.14159, 1.00614*10^-16}
```

and you get the point where the integration was stopped, without needing to produce the usual `InterpolatingFunction[]` output.