# How can I improve the smoothness of my NDSolve solution?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, options

This will, unfortunately, be a broader question than I prefer, but I do have a concrete example.

I simulate many oscillatory systems with NDSolve. For short simulation times, the result is generally excellent. For longer times, the oscillations get jagged and visibly not-smooth. I find the array of options in NDSolve regarding accuracy, maximum step size, and maximum step count very confusing.

The NDSolve shown below is inferior to a 4th order Runge-Kutta (from Matlab). (For the interested, these equations describe the oscillation of an optomechanical oscillator driven by a laser.) The RK step size is 3.57e-10 (see the picture generated below the code). Yet when I set MaxStepSize in the NDSolve to 3e-10, still the NDSolve solution is jagged when viewed in the same window (and destroys features such as the alternating peak heights). Clearly the sampling rate is too low.

I have done my best to review the NDSolve options in the help; is there some other option that I have failed to tune correctly? (I also have a working Runge-Kutta in Mathematica, but as it employs loops, it is far too slow to use for longer simulations times.)

(1) How can improve the smoothness of this simulation, specifically? (2) Generally, which option does it seem I have overlooked and may save me this grief next time around? I can tolerate slow calculation, but not poor fidelity. Thanks very much.

```
m = 5*10^-11;
b = 1.4*10^-6;
k = 57559.5;

ringEqn = m r''[t] + b r'[t] + k r[t] == 1.02*10^-8 (Abs[A[t]])^2;

NW = 182.1;
DeltaW[t_] = 1.42*10^7 - 1.483*10^19 r[t];
ampEqn = A'[t] + A[t] (2.58*10^7 - I DeltaW[t]) == 3.74*10^8 I;

myInits = {r[0] == 0, r'[0] == 0, A[0] == 0};

myVars = {A, r};

OMOsol = NDSolve[{{ringEqn, ampEqn}, myInits}, 
  myVars, {t, 0, .000036}, MaxStepSize -> 3*10^-10, 
  MaxStepFraction -> .0000001]

amp = Evaluate[A[t] /. OMOsol];
Plot[(Abs[amp])^2, {t, 0, m/b},
   PlotRange -> {{.9*10^-5, 1*10^-5}, {0, 60}},
   Frame -> True]
```

[image: Plot of (Abs[amp])^2 using Mathematica NDSolve]

Above: Mathematica--plot of (Abs[amp])^2 with above NDsolve

[image: Plot of (Abs[amp])^2 using 4th order Runge-Kutta in Matlab with step size h=3.57e-10]

Above: Matlab--plot of (Abs[amp])^2 using 4th order Runge-Kutta with step size h=3.57e-10

Comment: see here to plot the actual solve output data without interpolation.  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162781/2079. (In this case you have so many points it is extremely slow though)

Comment: note the results look pretty good (and much faster) without specifying `MaxStepSize` or `MaxStepFraction`

Comment: Thanks, I had not realized that this was an option, I wished I'd stumbled on it sooner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just increase [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) in `Plot`.  I tried 400 and got a nice result.  BTW, it seems to run fine, and much faster, without `MaxStepSize -> 3*10^-10, MaxStepFraction -> .0000001`.

```
OMOsol = NDSolve[{{ringEqn, ampEqn}, myInits}, myVars, {t, 0, .000036}]

Plot[(Abs[amp])^2, {t, 0, m/b}, PlotRange -> {{.9*10^-5, 1*10^-5}, {0, 60}},
  Frame -> True, PlotPoints -> 400]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh, thank you, very helpful! I didn't realize this could be the source of my issue, since I had chalked it up to an NDSolve issue!

Answer (score 3):

From [Easy way to plot ODE solutions from NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134222/easy-way-to-plot-ode-solutions-from-ndsolve), one might use `ListLinePlot` on the `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
ListLinePlot[
 {A["Grid"], Abs@A["ValuesOnGrid"]^2} /. First@OMOsol // Transpose // Interpolation,
 PlotRange -> {{.9*10^-5, 1*10^-5}, {0, 60}}, Frame -> True]
```

Since the plot range is a small portion, it may be worth selecting a subset of the solution:

```
range = {.9*10^-5, 1*10^-5};
grid = Flatten[A["Grid"] /. OMOsol];
mask = UnitStep[# - .9*10^-5] UnitStep[1*10^-5 - #] &@grid // SparseArray;
dom = Span @@ Flatten@Clip[
    mask["NonzeroPositions"][[{1, -1}]] + {-1, 1}, {1, Length@grid}]
(*  14461 ;; 16054  *)

ListLinePlot[
 ({A["Grid"], Abs@A["ValuesOnGrid"]^2} /. First@OMOsol)[[All, dom]] //
    Transpose // Interpolation,
 PlotRange -> {{.9*10^-5, 1*10^-5}, {0, 60}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can see the steps easily using `Mesh`, as in Matlab. Like @ChrisK, I omitted `MaxStepSize -> 3*10^-10, MaxStepFraction -> .0000001`.  This is one way to see if the step size needs manual adjustment.

```
ListLinePlot[
 ({A["Grid"], Abs@A["ValuesOnGrid"]^2} /. First@OMOsol)[[All, dom]] // 
    Transpose // Interpolation,
 Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Small], Red}, 
 PlotRange -> {{.9*10^-5, 1*10^-5}, {0, 60}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]